# JQuery Tools: Can you nest non-ajax tabs inside of ajaxed tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

Can't seem to get this to work -- my ajax tabs load fine ... but, the nested tabs are not working.

Before I post some code, I'm just wondering if this is possible or not.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  Now go post some code ;)

Answer (score 0):

As long as all the tab containers have different ids, it should work perfectly. (although if you put to many but might start running slow on old computers)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the JQuery Tools tab library, but presumably after the AJAX tab content has loaded you will need to execute the jQuery Tools function to create tabs out of elements that haven't been processed.